# Yii2 Сложная фильтрация данных

Tags: база-данных, yii2, запрос

Есть необходимость отфильтровать данные в 1 поле поиска. Фильтрация по названию материала, его автору и к каким категориям принадлежит материал. Понятное дело, что это всё выполняется через orFilterWhere и 'like'. Фильтрацию по названию материала и ФИО автора я объединил, но как добавить фильтрацию по третьему полю, где в базе оно хранится в виде массива ID с типом string.

Запрос идет по таблице материалов:
int ID 
int user_id 
string title 
string categories

Таблицу с пользователями я заджоинил и вытащил нужные поля ФИО, но как быть с категориями? Эта таблица не связана ни с чем. В таблице материалов хранится строка с ID категорий в таком виде:

> 1,4,17,39

.
В любом другом месте я могу обрабатывать это поле и вытаскивать категории, но что сделать при выборке?

Answer (score 0):

Смог обойти двойным запросом в поиске.
Инициализируем public переменную в контроллере поиска, в моем случае она называется multisearch. Затем фильтрую по связанной таблице ИЛИ по названию

```
$query
    ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'user.lastname', $this->multisearch])
    ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->multisearch]);
```

Затем кэширую данные поля, чтобы потом их вернуть нормально и проверяю на то, чтобы поле было не пустым, иначе будет работать некорректно. После этого делаю запрос на категорию, фильтрую их по полю поиска, вытаскиваю совпавшие категории и уже потом проверяю таблицу с материалами по вхождению этих вытащенных IDшников:

```
$cache = $this->multisearch;
  if (!empty($this->multisearch)) {
    $categories = Category::find()->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->multisearch])->all();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      $this->multisearch = $category->id;
      $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'categories', $this->multisearch]);
    }
    $this->multisearch = $cache;
  }
```